# How to unregister device backbutton on moving to model or when moving to another page from sidemenu

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, back-button

I have override the `registerbackbuttonaction` inside my home page and `unregistering` my backbutton action ionViewDidLeave it works fine when i push to another page from my home page.

**Issues:**

> I have written `this.nav.push("pagename")` inside my `app.component.ts` file For side menu items. because of this i am not able to go back onclick of device back button after over-ridding the device back button.
>
> When i remove the over-ridding back button function from my entire app i am getting the output what i am expecting.
>
> This also happens when on opening `model` page also my lifecycle event is not triggering.

Here is my code

ts file

```
initializeBackButtonCustomHandler(){

    let self = this
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      
    self.unregisterBackButtonAction = self.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
      if (this.menuCtrl.getOpen() != null) {
        this.menuCtrl.close();
        return
      }else if(this.modal && this.modal.index === 0) {
        console.log("invoking modal value")
        /* closes modal */
        // this.modal.dismiss();
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
        return
        
      }
      this.toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: "Press back again to exit the app",
        position: 'bottom',
        duration: 1500
      });
        this.toast.present();
        this.clickCount = this.clickCount + 1;
        this.toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
          this.clickCount = 0;
        })
        
      if(this.clickCount == 2){
        this.clickCount = 0;
        this.toast.dismiss();
          this.platform.exitApp();
      }
    }, 10)
  });
  }


  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.initializeBackButtonCustomHandler();

}

  ionViewDidLeave() {
    this.unregisterBackButtonAction && this.unregisterBackButtonAction();

}
```

The above code works fine when i do push it is unregistering the back button but for model and sidemenu part it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unregistering the back button you can pop to your previous page when it can go back and exit the app when it has no back state. I guess the following code could help you achieve this,

```
platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>{
          let nav = this.app.getActiveNav();
            if(nav.canGoBack()){
              nav.pop();
            }else{
                let ismodalopened=this.app._appRoot._modalPortal.getActive();
                if(ismodalopened){
                  app.navPop();
                }else{

                    let alertController = this.alertCtrl.create({
                      title: 'Confirm',
                      message: 'Are you sure you want to exit?',
                      buttons: [{
                        text: "Exit",
                        handler: () => { platform.exitApp(); }
                      }, {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        role: 'cancel'
                      }]
                    })
                    alertController.present();
                }         
            }
        });
```

Comment: The reason i need to unregistering is the default behaviour of backbutton pop() because we dont even need to handel every page and if i did registerbackbuttonaction on one page it is effecting the remaining page also

Answer (score 0):

The app.component is a special component. In effect it is your entire application, therefore it does not have ionic life-cycle events available to it. Only ionic pages have those events.

Also try to lower the priority of your back button listener from 10 to 0. Here is an example of one my team has implemented in app.component, we also recently added a are you sure modal popup before closing the app.

```
/**
 * Method will listen for native backButton on Android
 * Back:
 * If not at nav root will perform nav.pop() same as ionic menu back button.
 * Login:
 * Because of the behavior of backButton on mobile we need to force
 * the user back to the Azure logon page if they are not logged in .
 * Close App:
 * If at a root page and android will ask user if want to close app. Then react to yes/no. 
 */
public setupMobileBackButtonListener(): void {
    if (PlatformUtils.isMobile()) {
        this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
            let user = this.memoryStoreProvider.loginMemoryData().data;
            if (cmp.isUndefinedOrNull(user)) {
                this.platform.exitApp();
            }

            if (cmp.isDefinedAndNotNull(this.nav) && this.nav.length() === 1) {
                this.modalProvider.openYesNoActionModal(CLOSE_APPLICATION_QUESTION_MESSAGE).then(result => {
                    if (result === YES_NO_MODAL_YES_SELECTED) {
                        this.platform.exitApp(); // no back pages in queue exit app
                    }
                });
            } else {
                this.nav.pop(); // backPage
            }
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Notice the 0 priority and we never kill the listener. The downside of this is extra logic to make it work like the ionic back menu button.